# Pass current month date in parameter and get get prior month data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried this but no desired result in where clause

```
Convert(varchar(7), dateadd(mm, -1, getdate()), 120)
=Convert(varchar(7), @Paramtername, 120)
```

Comment: I removed all of your database tags because you are not using MySQL *and* SQL Server. Please add the tags that represent what RDBS you are actually using.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server:

To get the start of the prior month, you can use

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )-1, 0)
```

To get data for the prior month of a parameter you could use something like this:

```
where mydate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date_parameter )-1, 0)
  and mydate <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date_parameter )  , 0)
```